# Merged List by filling holes

Tags: python-3.x

We have few studies performed where we answer a few questions. These studies are stored in a table with non applicable questions answered as None.

We have a similarity function to determine similar questions answered in different studies.
We want to merge these two answers list to get a combined list.

Suppose we have 2 lists as :
`List1 : [None, None, 'a', 'b']`
`List2 : ['c', 'd', None, None]`

What is the best to merge the list as follows :
`ListMerged : ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']`

We want to preserve the order and remove the holes in the list.

One of the way is to iterate both the list simultaneously and determine the element.
Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: What if both are `None`.?

Comment: @SreeramTP : Then merge should contain `None`

Comment: The issue would be when both of them are not None, in that case issue a warn and pick any one (the first one always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension isn't the only way, but it certainly is the easiest.
Its a one liner -

```
List1 : [None, None, 'a', 'b']
List2 : ['c', 'd', None, None]
[x if x is not None else y for x,y in zip(List1,List2)]
```

Output:

```
Out[44]: ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```